# how to read/write objects to mpi file in java?

Tags: java, file, serialization, mpi

I am trying to write the results of some computation directly to a file, using the java-bindings from [open-mpi](http://www.open-mpi.org). I know it does not sound very "high-performance", but in my eyes it seems the easiest (and surest) way not to have to start all over again when I don't manage to finish my computations.

My code to write to the file looks as follows:

```
private Iterator<Object> writeAndCalculate(Iterator<Object> it) {
    int mode = MPI.MODE_WRONLY | MPI.MODE_CREATE | MPI.MODE_APPEND;
    try(mpi.File file = new mpi.File(MPI.COMM_WORLD, getFileName(), mode)) {
        Code code;
        long result;
        int counter = 0;
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Object o = it.next();
            if(counter++ == myRank) {
                //computations...
                byte[] buf = serialize(new Pair<Code, Long>(code, result);
                file.writeShared(buf, buf.length, MPI.BYTE);
            }
            if(counter == nrOfProcessors) 
                counter = 0;
        }
        it.remove();
    } catch (MPIException mpie) {
        mpie.printStackTrace();
    }

    return it;
}
```

where `serialize(Serializable)`looks like:

```
private byte[] serialize(Serializable object) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
        oos.writeObject(object);
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();   
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

I also got some code to deserialize:

```
private Object deserialize(byte[] buf) throws ClassCastException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);

    try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
        return ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return null;
}
```

The problem arises when I want to read the objects again, because I don't find how I could deserialize all objects in the file. I was trying to find something like:

```
private SortedMap<Code, Long> read() {
    SortedMap<Code, Long> result = new TreeMap<>();
    try(mpi.File file = new mpi.File(MPI.COMM_WORLD, getFileName(), MPI.MODE_RDONLY)) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) file.getSize()];
        file.readAll(buf, buf.length, MPI.BYTE);
        while(/*part of buf not read*/) {
            Pair<Code, Long> pair = deserialize(buf);
            result.merge(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue(), (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
        }
    } catch (MPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

but I have no idea how to find out what part of my buffer has been read and which part still contains objects. I had an idea to make `deserialize(byte[])` overwrite the values that have been read, but I have no idea on how to do something like that either.

Because I already spent hours on it, I am getting quite desperate and I would appreciate any help to make me see the light. If anybody could suggest better ways to write everything to one file from multiple processors simultaneously, feel free to leave suggestions.

I'm **sorry for the long question**, but all I need is some way to store (part of) the `SortedMap` that is the result from concurrent computation. This should be done in such way that when computations are cancelled or interrupted, I can start on from the point computation has stopped.